# How to deal with union/order by differences between HSQLDB and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hsqldb, dialect

I am currently using hsqldb for testing and mysql for production. This combination has worked great for me on every recent project, but I've come across a situation where HSQLDB's syntax/dialect is different from MySQL, and I'm not really sure what the best strategy is to overcome it.

In mysql, you can write a union query like this:

```
select ...
union
select ...
order by created_on desc
limit 20 offset 0
```

However, in HSQLDB, it complains that `order by` clause has an error.

Is there any way I can write the query so that both databases like the syntax?

Comment: have you tried with parenthesis around your selects?

Comment: I tried that. It still throws `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid ORDER BY expression`

Comment: please report the full SELECT columns as the error is related to which columns are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from (

select ...
union
select ...)a
order by a.created_on desc
limit 20 offset 0
```

Comment: Will this have a negative impact on performance? Just curious

Comment: I dont think there will be any notable performance difference.. as we are just giving an alias name for the result set

Comment: I think this will work. I will have to rewrite my java code though :( I was using a Hibernate's raw sql syntax, and it has special syntax to take {p.*} and put that into an object, but using your suggestion, I don't think I can use this Hibernate mapping shortcut anymore. I guess I'll just have to work with JDBC and do the mapping manually.